# Reuse Google Map v2 across several fragments in single Activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

One of my activities switches the fragments that contains google map.

At first I tried to use fragment's child fragment mananger (ChildFragmentManager) to add `SupportMapFragment`. It works ok, but map is loaded again for each fragment, which takes a lot of time.

I have failed to detach `SupportMapFragment` from one fragment and attach it to another, since it somehow connected with `ViewGroup` where it was placed first.

So finally I decided to use plain `MapView` object that is create in activity and add it to viewgroup of active fragment and remove it before placing in viewgroup of another fragment.

Everything works ok except `onSaveInstanceState` (MapView requires manually pass call all activity lifecycle methods like `onResume`, `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onSaveInstanceState`). When I try to call `mapView.onSaveInstanceState` in my activity it crushes the app.

I wonder if anybody else have successfully reused GoogleMap across several fragments?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using map fragment inside list item - I have just one fragment which is created and added to the `View` once and only once - I have an `ExpandableListView` and I'm adding it in adapter's `getChildView`.